# testing JSON ld script tag in next js HEAD component

Tags: reactjs, next.js, jestjs, react-testing-library

we are using next js for our project. We add structured data with json+ld format using  tag inside next js  tag .

now we add this json ld script tag conditionally.

**OurPage.tsx**

```
 <Head>
<title>{"meta title"}</title>
      <meta name="description" content="meta desc"} />
{ structuredData && <Script
          nonce={nonce}
          type="application/ld+json"
          // eslint-disable-next-line react/no-danger
          dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: structuredData }}
        />}
    </Head>
```

now i am trying to test this behaviour using react testing library and jest with help of jest.mock("next/head") as below.

```
jest.mock('next/head', () => {
  return {
    __esModule: true,
    default: ({ children }: { children: Array<React.ReactElement> }) => {
      return <>{children}</>;
    },
  };
});

const {debug}
 render(<OurPage />);
debug();
```

the problem is that the render screen has only meta "title" and "description" tags and missing "script" tag that is supposed to be present.

does anyone know how to fix this ?

Comment: I guess that `structuredData ` is falsy

Comment: i logged the structuredData and it's not falsy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try adding `data-testid="ldjson"` to your script tag.
I used here `script` tag, not the `nextjs/script` component as the [eslint](https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/no-script-component-in-head) screams about it. But this script does not load anything so anyway it should be OK to use `Script` tag.

```js
<script
  data-testid="ldjson"
  type="application/ld+json"
  dangerouslySetInnerHTML={addJsonLd()}
/>
```

and then in your test:

```js
const script = screen.getByTestId("ldjson");
expect(script).toBeDefined();
expect(script).toHaveTextContent("your expected value");
```

it looks like the RTL `debug` method does not render the scripts.

Comment: it worked.. but one question i have.
if RTL debug method does not render the scripts, how does adding "data-testid" help here ? it's still script tag at the end of the day right ?
i also have to keep ,
jest.mock('next/head', () => {
  return {
    __esModule: true,
    default: ({ children }: { children: Array<React.ReactElement> }) => {
      return <>{children}</>;
    },
  };
});

Comment: The debug method only shows some of the stuff. Here you can see that `script` tag is ignored: [link](https://github.com/testing-library/dom-testing-library/blob/main/src/config.ts#L28). The `screen.debug` is using `logDOM` method  which filters out `script` and `style` from `debug` method output here: [link](https://github.com/testing-library/dom-testing-library/blob/main/src/DOMElementFilter.ts#L249). So the `script` is there but the `debug` method does not show that. Why? No idea - you can ask in the repo issues.